# How to use the .place() method from Tkinter on a guizero object like pushbutton

Tags: python, tkinter, guizero

Hello I am trying to use the .place() Tkinter method on a guizero pushbutton object.
With Tkinter the code would look like

```
vidbutton = tk.Button(w, text="Video", command = connectgp)
vidbutton.place(relheight=0.176, relwidth=0.176, relx=0.02, rely=0.02)

shutterbutton = tk.Button(w, text="Shutter", command = connectgp)
shutterbutton.place(relheight=0.176, relwidth=0.176, relx=0.196, rely=0.02)
```

When executed the above code will show two buttons placed next to each other with the correct ratio of spacing, I am trying to implement this using guizero instead with the following code

```
connectbutton = PushButton(app, text="Connect Gopros", command=connect)
connectbutton.tk.place(relheight=0.176, relwidth=0.176, relx=0.02, rely=0.02)

videobutton = PushButton(app, text="Video", command=video)
videobutton.tk.place(relheight=0.176, relwidth=0.176, relx=0.196, rely=0.02)
```

For the guizero code only the last button made will display with the correct placement and the  `.place()` is completely ignored for the previous guizero objects.

Very confused and advice would help.

Comment: Try putting the two lines `xxxxx.tk.place(...)` after the creation of the two buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the Buttons Widget inside a Box Widget as its parent, you can get more details by following up with guizero layout guidance here:
https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/layout/#boxes
especially the alignment and location.

Based on what I tried, your code can give the same result of the standard tk if you made this adjustment:

```
from guizero import *

def connect():
    print("Connected!")


def video():
    print("Video!")

app = App(title="guizero")

botton_box = Box(app)
botton_box2 = Box(app)
botton_box.tk.place(relheight=0.176, relwidth=0.176, relx=0.02, rely=0.02)
botton_box2.tk.place(relheight=0.176, relwidth=0.176, relx=0.196, rely=0.02)

connectbutton = PushButton(botton_box,width="fill", height="fill", align="left", text="Connect Gopros", command=connect)
videobutton = PushButton(botton_box2, width="fill", height="fill", align="right",text="Video", command=video)


app.display()
```

The Layout will be like this based on your OS:
[image]

Comment: Hey @Loay would this method work if I want to have two buttons offset from each other at different y and x coordinates ?

Comment: Hey @Stasie, yes you can do that by using a separated Box for each Button, then use coordinates individually. I updated the code above, you can have a try. Anyway, this issue needs to be traced later in guizero to see why .place() can't be implemented directly on the Buttons.